# Warning: require_once(phing/BuildException.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, zend-framework, propel, phing

I'm new using Zend Framework 1.11 and Propel ORM together, and I get stuck on a very simple case. Here is the error on the url http://fle.localhost/domain :

> Warning: require_once(phing/BuildException.php): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/projects/library/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/lib/exception/EngineException.php
> on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'phing/BuildException.php'
> (include_path='/var/projects/fle-portal/application/models/propel:/var/projects/fle-portal/application/../library:/var/projects/library/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library:/var/projects/library/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/lib:/var/projects/library/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/lib:/var/projects/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
> in
> /var/projects/library/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/lib/exception/EngineException.php
> on line 11

My DomainController IndexAction is very simple :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
    $this->view->collDomains = Domain::getAll();
}
```

This one is calling a Propel object class in Domain.php :

```
<?php

/**
 * Skeleton subclass for representing a row from the 'domain' table.
 *
 * You should add additional methods to this class to meet the application requirements.
 * This class will only be generated as long as it does not already exist in the output
 * directory.
 * @package    propel.generator.fleazup
 */ 
class Domain extends BaseDomain
{
    public static function getAll()
    {
        return DomainPeer::doSelect(new Criteria());
    }
}
```

Also, nothing difficult in the view : views/script/domain/index.phtml :

```
<!-- CONDITION: if there are domains -->
<?php   
if (!empty($this->collDomains)):
?>

        <!-- if condition ok, display domains table -->
            <!-- Page header -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Domains List</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Flash messages -->
            <div>
                <?php if (count($this->messages)) : ?>
            
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
                        <ul id="messages">
                            <?php foreach ($this->messages as $message) : ?>
                                <li><?php echo $this->escape($message); ?></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Link to add action -->
            <div>
                <p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'domain', 'action'=>'add'));?>">Add a new domain</a></p>
            </div>

            <!-- domains table -->
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Label</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody> 
                    <?php foreach ($this->collDomains as $domain): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $this->escape($domain->getId()) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $this->escape($domain->getLabel()) ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'domain', 'action'=>'modify', 'id'=>$this->escape($domain->getId())));?>">Modify</a>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'domain', 'action'=>'delete', 'id'=>$this->escape($domain->getId())));?>">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        <!-- If condition KO -->
        <?php else: ?>
            <!-- Page header -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>Domains List</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Link to add action -->
            <div>
                <p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'domain', 'action'=>'add'));?>">Add a new domain</a></p>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Message -->
            <p>No domain to display.</p>

    <!-- End of condition -->           
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What I do not understand is that I did exactly the same with 2 other Objects and it works very well. I get the error only for the Domain object...

What do you think, where the error comes from ? Phing config ? Propel config ? Code ?
Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of conflict between your own Propel-generated model class `Domain` and the Propel vendor class which bears the same name in [the generator/lib/model folder](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/tree/master/generator/lib/model).

In fact, the error raised is misleading because it is triggered by the Propel vendor class being executed out of its context. When your code tries `Domain::getAll()`, the Propel vendor class throws an exception since the method `getAll()` does not exists. BUT, that exception can't be seen at first because `phing/BuildException.php` is not on the include path (context issue) : that's why occurs the initial error. Kind of tricky stuff, I confess.

You can fix this in prefixing your generated objects. To do so, set the `propel.classPrefix` property into your `build.properties` file  ([read the Propel documentation on Customizing Generated Object Model](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration.html#customizing_generated_object_model)) and rebuild your object model. Beware though, you will have to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Just ran into the same thing when I switched to the composer autoloader.  My naming conflict was my search index class `Index`.

Answer (score 0):

> require_once(phing/BuildException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is your issue. The file should exist, and you need to find out why it does not exist.